# Segment fault in realloc() on loop

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

I'm trying reallocate more 256 bytes to buffer on each loop call. In this buffer, I will store the buffer obtained from `read()`.

Here is my code:

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 256
//....
int sockfd = socket( ... );

char *buffer;
buffer = malloc( MAX_BUFFER_SIZE );
assert(NULL != buffer);
char *tbuf =  malloc(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
char *p = buffer;
int size = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;

while( read(sockfd, tbuf, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) > 0 ) {
    while(*tbuf) *p++ = *tbuf++;
    size = size + MAX_BUFFER_SIZE; // it is the right size for it?
    buffer  = realloc(buffer, size);
    assert(NULL != buffer); 
}


printf("%s", buffer);
free(tbuf); 
free(p);
free(buffer);
close(sockfd);
```

But the above code returns segment fault. Where am I wrong?

Comment: `while(*tbuf) *p++ = *tbuf++;` you are incrementing tBuf, which was malloc(0)d . You will never be able to free it, since you lost the original pointer. Hint: use `memcpy(p, tbuf, return_from_read);` Also the `while (*tbuf)` assumes a nul terminated string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the problems that are apparent to me:

- Your `realloc` can modify the location to which `buffer` points. But you fail to modify `p` accordingly and it is left pointing into the previous buffer. That's clearly an error.
- I see potential for another error in that the `while` loop need not terminate and could run off the end of the buffer. This is the most likely cause of your segmentation fault.
- The way you use `realloc` is wrong. If the call to `realloc` fails then you can no longer `free` the original buffer. You should assign the return value of `realloc` to a temporary variable and check for errors before overwriting the `buffer` variable.
- You should not call `free` on the pointer `p`. Since that is meant to point into the block owned by `buffer`, you call `free` on `buffer` alone.

Answer (score 2):

Thing is **`read` doesn't add a 0-terminator**. So your inner `while` is undoubtedly stepping outside the allocated memory:

```
while(*tbuf) *p++ = *tbuf++;
```

Another problem is that you are freeing stuff you didn't receive via malloc. By the time you call free, you will have incremented both `p` and `tbuff` which you try to free.

The whole `buffer` allocation things looks useless as you're not actually using it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `realloc` on `buffer`, it is possible that the address of `buffer` is changed as a result of changing the size. Once that happens, `p` is no longer holding the correct address.

Also towards the end, you are freeing both `p` and `buffer` while they point to the same location. You should only free one of them.